# Logic of applying Group by in Sql Queries

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am asking a very beginner level of question but I am always confused whenever I want to use aggregate function with Group by. Actually I am getting the right results but I am not pretty sure about how group by is working here. My requirement is to get the count of sent items which is based on MessageGroup columns.

```
MessageId    SenderId      MessageGroup                             Message
_____________________________________________________________________________

1                2         67217969-e03d-41ec-863e-659ca26e660f     Hi
2                2         67217969-e03d-41ec-863e-659ca26e660f     Hello
3                2         67217969-e03d-41ec-863e-659ca26e660f     bye
4                1         c45dc414-9320-40a5-8f8f-9c960d6deffe     TC
5                1         8486d16b-294b-45a5-8674-e7024e55f39b     shutup
```

Actually I want to get the count for sent messages.here SenderId=2 has sent three messages to someone but I want to show a single count so I have used MessageGroup and I am doing Groupby and getting the count.

I have used Linq query::

```
 return DB.tblMessage.Where(m => m.SenderId == 2 ).GroupBy(m => m.MessageGroup).Count();
```

This returns "1" which is correct and I want to show (1) in sent messages.

But if I try to query the above in SQL Server, it returns 3

Here is my SQL query:

```
select count(*) 
from tblMessage 
where SenderId = 2 
group by MessageGroup
```

The Linq query is right As it returns me one as Microsoft says [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Actually I am confused with Group by. Please clear my point.

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Do you want the unique `MessageGroup`-s for each `SenderId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you are using GroupBy, which ever columns present in groupBy Clause should be in Select Clause**

```
select MessageGroup,count(MessageGroup)from tblMessage 
where SenderId=2 
group by MessageGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to include MessageGroup as part of the select, like this:

```
select MessageGroup, count(*) 
from tblMessage 
where SenderId=2 
group by MessageGroup
```